# ArrayDeque to array

Tags: java, arrays, double, arraydeque

I have built an arraydeque and want to pass those Double values as an array to a constructor. The constructor is built to process the array values individually to a certain condition.

When using arraydeque its not allowing me to retrieve those double values (Iterater .next for loop) and store them in an array.

Are there any suggestions to correct this?

Comment: Yeah was going for an arraylist but this is fine. Not for anything major. Sould be able to use the deque directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Deque<Double> deque;
Double[] array = Double[deque.size()];
int count = 0;
for (Iterator<Double> i = deque.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    array[count++] = i.next();
}
```